# Looping Excel Solver Only Display Result for Last Row

Tags: excel, solver, vba

I want to loop Excel Solver through a number of rows.  But for some reason, the result is only displayed on the last row of the loop.  If I set the loop to only run on one row, I can see the result for the row (i.e. row 89 in the following sample code).  If I run it as below then I only see the result on row 101.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Sub solveForeLoop()

Dim r As Integer
For r = 89 To 101
SolverReset
SolverOptions Precision:=1e-05

SolverOK SetCell:="$Y$" & r, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$S$" & r

SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

SolverSolve

Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a bug in Mac Excel 2011.  I was able to successfully run the same code on Windows Excel 2010.